# Looking for books and/or other resources for Multivariate Statistics for Optimal Estimation

Tags: time-series, references, kalman-filter, state-space-models, sensor-data

I was trying to familiarize myself with state estimation theory by going through [Optimal State Estimation](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/0470045345.fmatter) and I realized I don't have the required background in Multiple Random Variables and Multivariate Stats.

But all books on these topics I can find seem to be geared towards experiment design or economics or biology. I obviously don't fully understand the significance of most of these topics but I've looked into it enough to understand that *NOVA analyses or hypothesis testing isn't quite what I need?- Please correct me if I'm wrong.

These are the topics I believe I'm looking for:

Multivariate Distributions- mostly Gaussians

Covariance and Correlation

<s>Principal Component Analysis and Factor Analysis</s>

Multivariate Time Series

Covariance Modelling

*Are there any books on Multivariable Statistics with these topics (ideally for self-study) that are geared towards Engineering applications?* My background is in Engineering. I know what a normal distribution is, what random vectors are and am familiar with linear algebra.

Comment: Hi: It's not that clear what the book has to do with some of the topics, particularly the last three. If you're trying to understand the Kalman Filter ( which I'm not so sure about given what you listed ), then it's really the first two that you should list.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah chatgpt gave me a list for "prerequisite topics in multivariate stats for state estimation". I was unsure about #3 but #4 and #5 seem relevant. The data I'm looking at is recursively sampled over time (from more than one sensor) and I should know how a covariance for a sensors measurements is estimated. As for Kalman filter yes but also other non linear estimators that might perform better.

Comment: Okay. I see. Thanks for explaining. For now, I don't think you need covariance modelling. There are so many KF books that I'm not sure what to recommend. Anderson and Moore along with Jazwinski are older KF bibles but I'm not sure what the modern ones are.